# C# Directory.Move but for an already existing folder - How to use this method or something similar without creating an entirely new directory?

Tags: c#, foreach, directory

```
switch (filesToAdd.Count)
        {
            case 0:
                Console.WriteLine("No files to ZIP detected. Returning to menu.");
                return;
            default:
                    Console.Clear();
                foreach (var file in filesToAdd)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Directory.Move(file, folderWithFolders);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                    }
                }

                break;
        }
```

This code constantly catches the exception where *folderWithFolders* already exists, because I create it earlier on based on user input.

Ideally, it should contain multiple folders that are stored in the list *filesToAdd* once the switch statement default case is finished.

Is it possible to use this *Directory.Create* method without creating an entirely new directory (since that means that it will be impossible for me to add every folder from the list) and instead be able to add a folder at a time through the *foreach* loop to *folderWithFolders* without creating a new directory; do any such methods exist?

Thank you.

Edit: So just in case someone stumbles upon this a few months in the future, I got it working by doing the following:

I changed:

```
try 
{ 
    Directory.Move(file, folderWithFolders); 
}
```

Instead I changed it to:

```
try 
{ 
    Directory.Move(file, folderWithFolders + "\\"
    + Path.GetFileName(file)); 
}
```

Comment: So I got this working by changing:
`try 
{ Directory.Move(file, folderWithFolders);
}` 
 - Instead I changed it to:
`try 
{ Directory.Move(file, folderWithFolders + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file));
}`

Comment: are you trying to move a file with Directory.Move?

Comment: @MelGerats Yup. I am moving multiple directories from different sources into one main folder to zip it later, since anything relating to ZipArchive required recursion and it was going a little over my head. For all intents and purposes, what I've done now works more-or-less fine, except the files are moved instead of copied but I should be able to change that easily enough.

Comment: but does the variable `filesToAdd` contain file paths or paths to folders with files in them? I have a hard time matching the code to your questions

Comment: Yeah, so `filesToAdd` is just a list that contains strings that are the folder paths, so for example with a folder selector, a string is stored in the list that might be like follows `C:\Users\Dev\FolderNameHere`. Hope that makes sense? :)

Answer (score 0):

If indeed `filesToAdd` is the list of folders you want to move to the folder `folderWithFolders`, then I would suggest

```
foreach (var file in filesToAdd)
{
    try
    {
        Directory.Move(file, Path.Combine(folderWithFolders,file)); 
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```